# How to run threads sequentially in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sequence

I have some timers that are updating a DataSet. I need the timers to run sequentially without bumping into each one after the other. I might be running only one or two or three at the same time. So the idea is they have to run 1,2,3 and then again 1,2,3. I created this fiddle but I don't have it down yet:

```
                class Example
            {
                private static ManualResetEvent mr = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                private static AutoResetEvent event_1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
                private static AutoResetEvent event_2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                private static void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    //update ds inside here
                    //ds.Tables["Alarms"].Rows[0][0]="foo";
                    //same in all other Tick functions
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                    mr.Set();
                }
                private static void t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    mr.WaitOne();
                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    mr.Set();
                }
                private static void t3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    mr.WaitOne();
                    Console.WriteLine("3");
                    mr.Set();
                }
                static void Main()
                {
                    System.Timers.Timer t1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    t1.Elapsed += t1_Tick;
                    t1.Enabled = true;
                    System.Timers.Timer t2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    t2.Elapsed += t2_Tick;
                    t2.Enabled = true;
                    System.Timers.Timer t3 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    t1.Elapsed += t1_Tick;
                    t1.Enabled = true;

                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
            }
```

If there are only two timers running it would have to be 1,2 an then again 1,2

Comment: Are you really, really dead set on these things happening in exact sequence?  If not, protect your database access with a `lock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a thread-safe `DispatcherTimer` instead?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

Comment: Is it possible I could see an example? The documentation example is for one timer only.

Comment: @user2209542 I just added a link to MSDN.

Comment: DispatcherTimer is the answer. With no modification at all the index corrupted exception happening to the DataSet object is not there any longer.